# SQL Filtering by Custom Column

Tags: sql-server, filtering, case

I am wondering if I can easily filter my results based on my "Style" column in my query.

```
select distinct
  m.ManagerName, 
  p.ProductName, 
  p.slocumrank,
  case 
    when s2.SubType2ID = 45 then 'Large Cap' 
    else s2.SubType2Name 
  End + ' ' + s1.SubType1Name as 'Style'
from QuantPerformance qp
where Style = 'ABCD'
```

Currently, my where statement filters out everything.

Comment: What does your data look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT  ManagerName
               , ProductName
               , slocumrank
               , case when SubType2ID = 45 
                      then 'Large Cap' 
                      else  SubType2Name 
                 End + ' ' + SubType1Name  AS  [Style]
from QuantPerformance
 ) A
where A.Style = 'ABCD'
```

### OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ManagerName
               , ProductName
               , slocumrank
               , case when SubType2ID = 45 
                      then 'Large Cap' 
                      else  SubType2Name 
                 End + ' ' + SubType1Name  AS  [Style]
from QuantPerformance
where case when SubType2ID = 45 
           then 'Large Cap' 
           else  SubType2Name 
      End + ' ' + SubType1Name = 'ABCD'
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot even after all these years ;)